# Javascript Array: what is a Big O of performing sort and then map right after on it?

Tags: javascript, performance, sorting, time-complexity, big-o

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a - b).map(num => num ** 2);
```

What would be a Big O of the following operation?

As I understand Big O of imbedded `sort` function in JS is `O(Nlog(N))` and Big O of `map` is `O(N)`, therefore Big O is `O(Nlog(N))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The complexity of your function `f`, for `arr` of size `n`. We'll assume:

```
arr.sort ∈ O(nlogn)
arr.map ∈ O(n),
```

We can just sum these terms, since these operations are done serially (one after the other. Thus,

```
f(n) ∈ O(nlogn + n)
```

Note that the `nlogn` term will grow slowly, but eventually:

```
as n -> infinity, nlogn >> n
thus, as n -> infinity, nlogn + n -> nlogn
```

So we can simplify to just `O(nlogn)` for sufficiently large `n`.

All of this is to say, yep, you got it.

Comment: Agreed, since they are running in series, one after the other, you would add O() for each.

Comment: That's a great point of clarification that I left out, thank you! Very important to note that these operations are in no way nested, so we can just add up terms.

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess I have a follow up question:

If I have a function where I'm supposed to perform such operation on 2 arrays (not nested), then it will be O(nlogn + nlogn) => O(2nlogn), where 2 will be ignored since it is constant and therefore the whole wrapper function will be O(nlogn)?

Basically as long as it is no functions nested inside each other it will not escalate to being quadratic, right?

Comment: @Konstantink1 Yeah absolutely. Constant terms can be eliminated, and you'll only end up with a quadratic if you can find a quadratic term to squash the nlogn term (often seen in, ex doubly nested variable-length loops). I'd suggest trying to understand the formal definition of big-oh notation on wikipedia and do some exercises trying to find specific values for constant terms, minimum n values etc with some of your own code.